# solution for delivering statistical files Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I'm not very good at nginx, I'm doing some images through urls

Ex: {my domain}/img/hello/picture.png*

I would like to change to *{my domain}/img /{md5}/picture.png*,

thus leaving *{my domain} /img/5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592/picture.png*

I ask is it possible to create an overwrite function or some other means in nginx?

Comment: Even if nginx could do it (which cannot, to my knowledge), what's the point of doing that? as soon as you keep picture.png in the path and for non-sensitive static resources..?

Comment: Yes it would be just for standardization

Answer (score -1):

It is possible but you have to modify your end point not Nginx file for that.
you can write Nginx file like this :

```
server{
      listen 80 default_server;
      listen [::]:80 default_server;
      server_name 127.0.0.1;


      location / {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
      }
}
```